# How to get javascript proxy from WCF service webHttpBinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, json, wcf

I setup all my endpoint, binding and behavior in order to consume the service using json, but now I can't figure how to generate the javascript proxy in order to access from my client javascript JQuery code through Ajax. Any ideas?

Please, don't try to suggest me to use a server side approach between WCF and the client (for example, asp.net mvc action cosuming the service), thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="IServiceForJQuery">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Behavior1"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" name="Endpoint1"
          contract="IServiceForJQuery" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior1">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rick Strahl has got a [blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Sep/15/Making-jQuery-calls-to-WCFASMX-with-a-ServiceProxy-Client) on this.

He has created a Script Proxy class you can use to call the service.

Comment: The post is from 2009?